# inheritance and attribute packed

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

Consider this code in C++

```
struct Base
{
   std::int64_t x;
   std::int64_t y;
};
static_assert(sizeof(Base) == 16, "Base not of size 16!");

struct Derived : Base
{
   std::int32_t z;
}__attribute__((packed));
static_assert(sizeof(Derived) == 20, "Derived not of size 20!");
```

clang considers this code valid, where as gcc results in firing of the second static_assert. ("Derived not of size 20!). If I add attribute packed in Base as well, then it is fine in both the compilers. Does anyone know which one is right and why?

Comment: Both of them are right. In general, issues of alignment, and packing, are implementation-defined.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this also varied for different versions of Clang and/or different build environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are right.

The compiler is allowed to add padding to your class (between members and at the end) and it is implementation defined whether it does or not, so your `static_assert`'s are basically testing something that depends on the compiler (and platform) used - thus they are not portable and you can't expect the same result everywhere.

Your use of `__attribute__((packed))` basically tells the compiler(s) who understand the attribute, that you want a specific behaviour rather than what it would do by default. This may generate the result you want in this case, but it also has implications (memory layout/use and on some CPUs performance). And you still can't be certain that all compilers will do the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is an implementation defined concept, that differs among implementations and compiler.

As said, the compiler is allowed to add extra space to the class, and code like what you wrote is not portable. The amount of space, or padding added is different by compiler, and no code can have a solid check that will satisfy everything. This will lead to different results in different places, because, all compilers are different.